# list combinations

Tags: java, recursion

How to list combinations in java with methods that stack upon each other.

Answer (score 1):

To print the combinations, you need to print when `amount == 0`.

To do that, you need to accumulate what has been done to get to that value, i.e. which coins has been applied to the `amount` value.

One way would be to build a string, appending a space and the coin value as part of the recursive call. The resultant string will start with a space, so it has to be skipped when printing.

```
public static int combo(int amount, int currentCoin, String combo) {
//                                          Added: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    if (amount == 0) {
        System.out.println(combo.substring(1)); // <<<<< Added
        return 1;
    }
    if (amount < 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int nCombos = 0;
    for (int coin = currentCoin; coin < coins.length; coin++) {
        nCombos += combo(amount - coins[coin], coin, combo + " " + coins[coin]);
        //                                  Added: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }

    return nCombos;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println("combo = " + combo(20, 0, ""));
//                                  Added: ^^^^
```

*Output*

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 5
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 5
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 5
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 5
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 5 5
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 5
1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 5 5
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 5
1 1 1 1 1 5 5 5
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 5 5
1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 5
1 1 1 2 5 5 5
1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 1 2 2 2 2 5 5
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 5
1 2 2 5 5 5
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 5 5
5 5 5 5
combo = 29
```

Comment: You have to remove it again, because you're updating a shared object. All levels of recursing through your method will shared the same list object, unlike the string version shown here, where each recursion will receive a different string.

Comment: that makes sense! but I tried making a new list in the loop each time (like the string), but it gave me an incorrect output. do you have any idea why?

Comment: @user11452926 Depends on how you "made a new list", I guess. If you did `newList = list`, then you just made another reference to the same list. If you did `newList = new ArrayDeque<>(list)`, then you correctly made a *copy* of the existing list.

Comment: Thank! It seems like to me that both strings and Lists are shared objects though. do you know where I can read more about this?

Comment: @user11452926 Strings are immutable, so `combo + " " + coins[coin]` creates a **new** string, i.e. every invocation will receive a different string, i.e. the string is not shared between invocations.